# User's return null on option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

I'm trying list my data to select's options.I'm using handlebars backbone jquery requireJS.

userselectlist.js

```
var users = new UserCollection();
var SelectUserList = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: User,
    el:'.page',
    render:function(users)
    {

        var template = Handlebars.compile(SelectUserListTemplate);
        var html = template({users:users.toJSON()});
        console.log(users);//This line
       $("#userSelect").html(html);
    }
});

return {
    users:users,
    SelectUserList:SelectUserList
};
```

my select-user-list.html

```
    <option value="">Kullanıcı Seçiniz</option>
{{#each users}}
<option value='{{userID}}'>{{firstName}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

index.html

```
            <div class="page">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="userSelect"></select>
            </div>
```

router.js

```
  user:function(){
  $('body').after(spinner.spin().el);
        var users = new Users();
        var userSelect = new UserSelectList.SelectUserList();
        users.fetch({

            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (m_users) {
                m_users.each(function (m_model) {
                    spinner.stop();
                    var userList = new UserSelectList.SelectUserList();
                    UserSelectList.users = new Users();
                    userList.render(m_model);
                });
                }
```

My problem is user's printing with console.log .But select tag has a null option line.If you don't understand(sorry of my english) , you can look this ScreenShot

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: `UserSelectList.users = new Users();` Seems like you are needing to pass data into that constructor. The way it is I don't see those object containing anything from your AJAX response.

Comment: console.log(users) return all user on userselectlist.js . I mean users have my datas . So how i pass data into the constructor. I try UserSelectList.users=m_model; on router.js but not work @MattSizzle

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="">Kullanıcı Seçiniz</option>
{{#users}}
<option value='{{userID}}'>{{firstName}}</option>
{{/users}}
```

I deleted "each" tags and work it.